# When there's no grub, how to change gpu kernal parameters?

Tags: linux, grub, uefi, bios, kernel-parameters

I currently use dual AMD R9 gpus. However, I recently was forced to upgrade motherboards and to the next version of my linux distro. My old motherboard was BIOS based, and my new one is UEFI based.

Both setups have the problem of defaulting to radeon drivers over amdgpu drivers.

```
03:00.0 VGA compatible controller: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI] Hawaii PRO [Radeon R9 290/390] (rev 80)
    Subsystem: XFX Pine Group Inc. Hawaii PRO [Radeon R9 290/390]
    Kernel driver in use: radeon
    Kernel modules: radeon, amdgpu
```

With my old bios-based mobo, all I had to do was add

`GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="radeon.cik_support=0 amdgpu.cik_support=1 radeon.si_support=0 amdgpu.si_support=1"`

to

`etc/default/grub`

in order to add the kernal boot parameter, and to ensure it'd default to the vulkan-based drivers.

But now, with the fresh install in a UEFI environment, there **is no such file**

So I have no idea what to edit/change/install to get the same effect?

**Edit**: To the suggestion of the comments, I hopped into

`/boot/efi/loader/entries/current.conf`

and changed this line

`options root=UUID=[drive-UUID] ro quiet loglevel=0 systemd.show_status=false splash`

to this line

`options root=UUID=[drive-UUID] ro loglevel=0 radeon.cik_support=0 amdgpu.cik_support=1 radeon.si_support=0 amdgpu.si_support=1`

and restarted.

However, a `lspci -k | grep -EA3 'VGA|3D|Display'`  still gives me the same results?

Comment: that depends on what your bootloader actually _is_. you might still be using GRUB, though its files would be somewhere inside `/boot/efi` now. or you might be using systemd-boot, or possibly another EFI-based bootloader

Comment: is there a good way to find out? There is a ```/boot/efi``` folder, but even with sudo, I can't get into it.

Comment: Have you tried `grubby`? Even tho it is named that, it should work with GRUB, GRUB2, LILO, etc. You most likely have GRUB2 in [U]EFI mode and it should find it.

Comment: What's grubby? I'm not seeing it in apt...

Comment: @Fox I got into ```/boot/efi``` and it did look like there were options there for me to work with in ```/boot/efi/loader/entries``` (there was a loader.conf in /loader as well, but it looked built purely to call an entry of choice). I went into the current loader conf in entries, and found what looked like a good spot and added my entries. However, they don't seem to take when I restart. I know with grub you had to rebuild from the file. Is there an equivalent here?

Comment: Lets see details, use ppa version with your live installer (2nd option) or any working install,  not Boot-Repair ISO:
Please copy & paste the pastebin link to the Boot-info summary report ( do not post report), do not run the auto fix till reviewed.
 https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Repair

Comment: @oldfred I can boot into my system just fine, it's just that it's using the radeon graphics drivers instead of the amdgpu graphics drivers, which means lots of advanced graphics capabilities are unavailable (in other words, vulkan), I'm not needing a boot-repair, per se, but a kernal parameter option set (unless I'm misunderstanding you?)

Comment: More to see configuration, not necessarily fix booting.

Comment: @oldfred My install disk just launches into a live desktop, there aren't any options sets as I'm understanding you. Is there a command I could run on my installed OS to get you the info you're looking for?

Comment: If you look at the link and second option it shows that you run the commands to add a ppa to the live installer, update & run Boot-Repair using terminal. It can be run from a working install, also.

Comment: A couple copecks more just in case these help someone...

Check with a LiveCD that "Both setups have the problem of defaulting to radeon drivers over amdgpu drivers" is still the _current_ problem indeed -- R7 GPUs used to be driven by both radeon.ko and amdgpu.ko but RX only go with amdgpu.ko (don't have R9 handy to check myself).

If you still use a Debian-based distro on a GRUB-capable platform, chances are that your `/etc/default/grub` (check by *absolute* path, the one you gave might most likely be valid *if* your CWD is /).